# how do i supply textbox values to my sql statement using Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, ado.net, dapper

The error message for both button clicks is:

Additional information: The member Id of type System.Windows.Controls.TextBox cannot be used as
a parameter value

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {

        var connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

        Student student = new Student();

        connection.Open();
        
        var affectedRows = connection.Execute("Delete from Student Where Id = @Id", new { Id = txtStudentID });

            connection.Close();

            //return affectedRows;
    }











    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

        Student student = new Student();

        var affectedRows = connection.Execute("Update Student set Name = @Name, Marks = @Marks Where Id = @Id", new { Id = txtStudentID, Name = txtName.Text, Marks = txtMarks.Text });

        connection.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the Text inside the textbox as the parameter value, not the TextBox itself

```
connection.Execute(
  "Delete from Student Where Id = @Id", 
  new { Id = txtStudentID.Text }
//                       ^^^^^
);
```

It would be best not to ask SQL Server to do a data conversion. If the ID column in the database is an integer, parse the string to integer on C# side:

```
connection.Execute(
  "Delete from Student Where Id = @Id", 
   new { Id = int.Parse(txtStudentID.Text) }
);
```

Or use a NumbericUpDown control then you don't have to worry about parsing failures (only numbers can be entered)

```
connection.Execute(
  "Delete from Student Where Id = @Id", 
  new { Id = (int)nudStudentID.Value }
);
```

Similarly if the ID is e.g. a Guid, parse it..

Same advice for the update query - you've got the `.Text` on the name and the Marks (it's numeric? see parsing advice above), but not on the ID; perhaps a copypasta error

---

Other bits of advice:

You should write `using var` to create your connection. You don't need to make a new Student. Dapper will open/close a connection that is closed. It will leave open a connection that is opened by you. You don't use affected rows, so you don't need to capture it:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using var connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

    connection.Execute(
        "Update Student set Name = @Name, Marks = @Marks Where Id = @Id", 
        new { 
          Id = int.Parse(txtStudentID.Text), 
          Name = txtName.Text, 
          Marks = double.Parse(txtMarks.Text)
        }
    );

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  you pointed out mistakes. I am just a learning. working well now.

Comment: No problem! If your question is resolved you can click the gray check mark next to it to turn it green. This changes the appearance of the question on the dashboard so that people know you're not still looking for an answer

Answer (score 0):

Is txtStudentID a control?
If so you should use the Text property of txtStudentID. If its a numeric datatype then you could try to .ToString() it.

Comment: textbox name, ID